# Docker - Issue dockerizing flask app when the file exists in that path

Tags: docker, flask

I am trying to dockerize a flask app using the below code:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:4.4.0
COPY . /demo_app
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /demo_app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "flask_app", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

I am trying to run the docker app using the below code:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 test_app
```

I however am getting an error

```
python: can't open file 'flask_app': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems to be a path error. Try `["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]`

Comment: @ParthShah but the manage.py file is in the path `demo_app/flask_app/manage.py` .. So changing it to the above would it be able to find that file..

Comment: Switch up `WORKDIR` to `/demo_app/flask_app` after running pip install.

Answer (score 0):

`demo_app/flask_app/` this is the directory, where python expecting fileName.

```
 python FlaskApp.py
```

[how-run-flask-application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application)

So either change `workdir` or change the `cmd`.

```
WORKDIR /demo_app/flask_app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Or change the `CMD` but make sure import should not break by doing this

```
CMD ["python","flask_app/manage.py", "runserver"]
```